# Javascript regular expression to extract characters from mid string with optional end character

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to extract characters from mid string with optional end character.  If the optional end character is not found, extract until end of string. The first characters are S= and the last optional character is &.

Example #1:

```
"rilaS=testingabc"
```

should extract:

```
"testingabc"
```

Example #2:

```
"rilaS=testing123&thistest"
```

should extract:

```
"testing123"
```

This is what I have so far (Javascript):

```
var Str = "rilaS=testing123&thistest";
var tmpStr = Str.match("S=(.*)[\&]{0,1}");
var newStr = tmpStr[1];
alert(newStr);
```

But it does not detect that the end should be the ampersand (if found). Thank you before hand.

**Answer (By ggorlen)**

```
var Str = "rilaS=testing123&thistest";
var tmpStr = Str.match("S=([^&]*)");
var newStr = tmpStr[1];
alert(newStr);
```

Comment: `Str.match("S=(.*)[\&]");` is not enought ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use `/S=([^&]*)/` to grab from an `S=` to end of line or `&`:

```js
["rilaS=testingabc", "rilaS=testing123&thistest"].forEach(s =>
  console.log(s.match(/S=([^&]*)/)[1])
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you are wondering *why* your original regex didn't work: the problem is that the (.*) pattern is *greedy* - meaning it will happily slurp up anything, including &, and not leave it for for later items to match.  This is why you want the "not &" - it will match up to, but not including the &.